how to package r scripts as plugin to qgis?
I was wondering if it is possible to make a QGIS plugin (install from zip) or something similar to how python is packaged as plugin but for R scripts that are developed as r/processing scripts in QGIS. I would like to exchange/package my scripts to share with others.
Thank you.

I'm not aware about such functionality, in fact R scipts are executed through R processing provider plugin (https://north-road.github.io/qgis-processing-r/). If you wish to share -- please make it public. Place on github/gitlab/somewhere. There is a resource sharing plugin (https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/) where you could be able to add yours resources as well.
